# jQuery replace() not working for entire html content

Tags: jquery

I have a html temple and it's field's name is started with 'SAMPLE'. Using jQuery I need to get entire html content and remove all SAMPLE text from that and add the updated html content to another div. Here is my code. Sample code here : http://jsfiddle.net/m4fLb85L/

```
<div class="sample_data" style="display:none;">
    <div style="float:left; margin-right:5px; width:75px;" class="sizes_element">
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <select class="size-selector" listkey="2" name="SAMPLEsize2[38]">
                <option value="22">X</option>
                <option value="23">L</option>
                <option value="24">M</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div><input class="SAMPLEsquantity" style="text-align:center;" type="text" name="SAMPLEqty2[38]" value="0"></div>
        <div><input class="SAMPLEsprice" style="text-align:center;" type="text" name="SAMPLEprice2[38]" value="0.00"></div>
        <div><input class="SAMPLEsofferprice" style="text-align:center;" type="text" name="SAMPLEofferprice2[38]" value="0.00"></div>
        <div style="text-align:center;"><input class="SAMPLEsdefault" type="checkbox" name="SAMPLEdefault2[38]"></div>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

jQuery part

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var sData = $('.sample_data').html().replace('SAMPLE','');
    $('#output').html(sData);
});
```

My problem is the SAMPLE text is removed only first element. But I need to remove that from entire html content. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use with **[RegExp g Modifier](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp)**:

```
sData = $('.sample_data').html().replace(/SAMPLE/g, '');
```